# Handle empty list inside "in" clause of criteriaBuilder in Java

Tags: java, hibernate-criteria

How to handle empty list inside "in" clause in `criteriaBuilder`?

Belows code is wrong if :

```
valueList = empty ArrayList:
predicateList.add(builder.or(something.get("column1").in(valueList), builder.equal(something.get("column1"), 0) ));
```

Is it possible to handle it with some `criteriaBuilder` methods?

Comment: maybe [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#isEmpty-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-) is util

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo - nope. this method check if the result is not null. I want to search via valueList if it is not empty OR searching by 0 value.

Comment: How about splitting that line into multiple parts and just add the "in"-builder if the list is not empty? Alternatively, your predicate basically states `column1 == 0 or column1 in (list)` - why not build a copy of the list and always add 0 thus making it `column1 in (0, list)`?